# AWS Route 53 CNAME with long destination URL not allowed

Tags: amazon-route53, cname

I'm adding a CNAME entry into Route 53. The URL I'm trying to redirect **to** (i.e. destination) has a large number of characters. When I try to add it I get this error:

```
Error occurred
Bad request.
(InvalidChangeBatch 400: DomainLabelTooLong (Domain label is too long) encountered with '<my-url>', Unparseable CNAME encountered)
```

After some fiddling it looks like it gives me this error if the URL is longer than **70 characters**. If the URL has less than that, it works fine. I can't find anywhere documenting this limit, so is it a bug? Is there any way to increase this limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the relevant information from the [Route53 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DomainNameFormat.html):

> Domain names (including the names of domains, hosted zones, and
> records) consist of a series of labels separated by dots. Each label
> can be up to 63 bytes long. The total length of a domain name cannot
> exceed 255 bytes, including the dots.

Wikipedia provides [similar information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Domain_name_syntax,_internationalization):

> A label may contain zero to 63 characters. The null label, of length
> zero, is reserved for the root zone. The full domain name may not
> exceed the length of 253 characters in its textual representation. In
> the internal binary representation of the DNS the maximum length
> requires 255 octets of storage, as it also stores the length of the
> name.